# Included pdf documents in latex are "twosided" but the overall document is "onesided", how can I change this?

Tags: pdfpages

I want to include a pdf document with a couple of pages in my dissertation. I used the package `pdfpages` to do so. When I specified `oneside` only in documentclass it did not work so included the package `typearea`. Now the whole document is onesided but the pdfs are twosided. Does anyone know how to fix this? Sorry if the included sample is a mess, I am not an expert yet and lot is trial an error :). Thank You !

Below my main document:

```
\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions} 
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{DissOnlineLatex}
\usepackage[DIV=14,BCOR=15 mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\include{command}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\include{hyphenations} 
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\setcounter{page}{1}
\selectlanguage{english}
\include{chapter01}
\include{paper01}
\end{document}
```

I included the pdf document as follows:

```
\includepdf[pages={1-7}, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, frame=false, scale=0.9, offset=10mm 0mm]{pdffiles/Paper1.pdf}
```

It creates a "shifted" pdf but the sides are in the "twoside" format.

Comment: So the pdf you want to include is in two-sided format? Do you have the source of the pdf you want to include? Also *don't* use `include` in your preamble! Only `input`.

Comment: I guess I found the problem. The pdf I wanted to include is actually a journal article and it is not centered as I thought but formated twoside... stupid me. I include the pdf with include because it is a chapter of my thesis and I want it to appear in the table of contents.

Comment: Yes include the pdf but don't use `\include{command}` and `\include{hyphenations}`. Include in the preamble is always a bad idea (and wrong).

Comment: Allright I will change that ! Thank you ! I just tested it with another pdf file that is not "twosided" but centered and it works perfectly.